# How does view layering affect a views positioning?

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This question has been re-written, since I think it has more to do with views and layers than the original 'Finding the center of a tableview'. Also in hope of finding another answer.

In question, is a set of 4 views to show activity, in a tableview, in a tab bar.

[image: First Display]

The code of:

```
NSLog(@"view.center: %@", self.view.center);
NSLog(@"view.frame: %@", self.view.frame);
```

Produces, on first display of 'loading':

```
view.center: {160, 250}
view.frame: {{0, 20}, {320, 460}}
```

For 2nd (and subsequent) displays: (after a pop up date picker)

```
view.center: {160, 205.5}
view.frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 411}}
```

Self (ListViewController) is subclass of UITableViewController. **So, the height of the view (or tableview) frame is changing. Why?**

I've been exploring and found this info in the debugger, that seems relevant.

```
--- Before ---
[self parentViewController]:
              <UITabBarController: 0x6e115a0>
[[self parentViewController] view]:
              <UILayoutContainerView: 0x6e1b750; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e0c8f0>>
self:         <ListsViewController: 0x6e13730>
[self tableView]: 
              <UITableView: 0x71e4000; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6834db0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
[[self view] subviews]:  (array)
              <UIImageView: 0x6825e30; frame = (0 453; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6835a90>>,
              <UIImageView: 0x68314e0; frame = (313 411; 7 20); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x683d120>>,
              <UIView: 0x6a054f0; frame = (0 0; 320 460); alpha = 0.4; tag = 12; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a07840>>,
              <UIView: 0x6a04c60; frame = (110 155.5; 100 100); alpha = 0.6; tag = 13; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a073c0>>,
              <UILabel: 0x6a07480; frame = (110 200.5; 100 50); text = 'Loading ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 14; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a065b0>>,
              <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0x6a07a80; frame = (140 167.5; 40 40); tag = 15; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a07b40>>

--- After datepicker ---
[self parentViewController]:
              <UITabBarController: 0x6e115a0>
[self parentViewController] view]:
              <UILayoutContainerView: 0x6e1b750; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e0c8f0>> 
self:         <ListsViewController: 0x6e13730>
[self tableView]:
              <UITableView: 0x71e4000; frame = (0 0; 320 411); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6834db0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
[[self view] subviews]:
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0xb642120; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 369; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb642230>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0xb643850; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 325; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb643960>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0xb6435c0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 281; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb6436d0>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0xb63cf30; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 237; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb63d130>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0x6a14050; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 193; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a16fb0>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0x6a13760; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 149; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a13870>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0x6a10920; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 105; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a10010>>,
              <DetailTableViewCell: 0xb63ce20; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 60; 320 45); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb63c3e0>>,
              <UIImageView: 0x6825e30; frame = (0 404; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6835a90>>,
              <UIView: 0xb6477f0; frame = (0 0; 320 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb647820>>,
              <UIImageView: 0x68314e0; frame = (313 411; 7 20); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x683d120>>,
              <UIView: 0x6a098a0; frame = (0 0; 320 411); alpha = 0; tag = 9; animations = { opacity <CABasicAnimation: 0xb6279f0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a154b0>>,
              <UIDatePicker: 0x6a23350; frame = (0 455; 320 216); tag = 10; animations = { position <CABasicAnimation: 0xb63bd40>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a20590>>,
              <UIToolbar: 0x6843f60; frame = (0 411; 320 44); opaque = NO; tag = 11; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0xb645f80>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6844a20>>,
              <UIView: 0xb60baa0; frame = (0 0; 320 411); alpha = 0.4; tag = 12; layer = <CALayer: 0xb626af0>>,
              <UIView: 0xb626b20; frame = (110 155.5; 100 100); alpha = 0.6; tag = 13; layer = <CALayer: 0xb626930>>,
              <UILabel: 0xb60cfb0; frame = (110 200.5; 100 50); text = 'Loading ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 14; layer = <CALayer: 0xb60d020>>,
              <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0xb649e20; frame = (140 167.5; 40 40); tag = 15; layer = <CALayer: 0xb626960>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableview.frame to access the origin points and it's dimensions. You can use tablview.center which is a CGPoint which gives you the center point of the object.

Comment: I thought that originally and added log statements with tableView in place of view. The log results were the same for 1st and subsequent. There is no difference (bounds, center and frame) between view and tableView.

Comment: well then the tableview must be overlapped by something (UITabBar?), also try setting the frame manually.

Comment: Setting the frame manually is not the question. I still search for why the controller's view and the table view have the same frame and bounds. And, why does self.tableView.Center give the center of the 320 X 480 window (on the 1st display) when a tabBar exists below the table?

Comment: No. In searching for answer, I've discovered this: Xcode only accepts self.tableView.frame. This is leading me to believe I'm accessing the wrong property

Comment: Maybe the previous answer is not clear. Using IB for the tableview, however, programmatically adding 3 views & an opaque view to the existing window with `[self.view addSubview:refreshViewSquare]`.

Comment: is one of them views your UITabBar? If so, there's your overlap.

Comment: This is not helping me to understand why the tableView.center property is different on the 1st and subsequent displays. @James Thanks for your replies.